# Is there a good way to store and organize try/combination squares?

Tags: tools, storage, bench

I have a bunch of try/combination squares that I would like to store/hang in my work area but I cannot figure out a good system. Can someone recommend a good method to keep combination squares readily available and protect them from getting damaged? I would like to have at least the following within reach of my bench:

- 1 × 6  inch try square
- 2 × 12 inch try square(s)
- 2 × 12 inch combination square(s)
- 1 × 24 inch protractor square
- 1 × 24 inch straight edge / ruler (bonus points)

Updated information to address question:

I do have a pegboard in front of my bench. That is what is so confounding. I have not been able to think of a way to securely store/hang them on the peg board. Despite the existence of the peg board answers do not need to utilize the pegboard.

Comment: Do you have a spot for pegboard over/near the bench?

Answer (score 5):

If all your tools are steel or other ferromagnetic material, I would try something like this:

[image]

It's a magnetic knife holder that you should be able to buy at any kitchen store.

Alternatively, you could build something along the lines of a traditional knife block by glue-laminating pieces of wood and leaving appropriate gaps for each square.  Although, some types of squares might not fit.

Comment: Yes, but what about aluminum or plastic?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: You already got the +1, but yes. And to be fair, you gave him alternatives that are material neutral.

Comment: Has anyone used a magnet strip like this on a pegboard? I am curious if it becomes a hassle with other metal tools nearby?

Comment: I actually like the idea a lot for a lot of my tools.  Now I will have to figure out where to get good cheap magnet strips.

Comment: For plastic or non-ferrous tools you could use binder clips, which will stick to the magnet, and can clip the square.

Answer (score -1):

I built a custom tool holder that works pretty well.  Woodsmith had a good article on pegboard holders: http://www.woodsmithshop.com/download/211/pegboardrack.pdf

Comment: -1 Link only answers become useless when the link goes bad and are frequently confused with spam. Be sure to provide context around the link and quote relevant content in case the link goes bad. See [how to answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for more details.